# How to find out UML associations from source code with Java reflection

Tags: java, reflection, uml

I'm working on a project that will be used to generate class diagrams from Java code. The tool takes jar-files as input and outputs Graphviz dot format files as output.

I know it's simple to find out inheritance and interface implementations using Java reflection with [Class#getSuperclass](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getSuperclass--) and [Class#getInterfaces](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getInterfaces--). But I'm struggling to find out associations, compositions and dependencies. Can it be done with reflection or is there some external library that would help? Any example code you might be able to provide would be of great help.

Comment: You could try [Apache BCEL](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-bcel/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Associations and compositions can be inferred from class fields, so [`Class#getDeclaredFields`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredFields--).

For dependencies you'd have to look at the code to see what classes might be used as variables, which you can't do using reflection. For that, you'd have to look at the bytecode of the .class files in the jar files, using a library such as [Apache Commons BCEL](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-bcel/).